# Ajax.BeginForm is always excecuting a 'POST'

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two ajax forms:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index2","Home", 
    new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "result", 
            HttpMethod = "PUT"
        }, 
    new
        {
            onclick = "Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event));",
            onsubmit="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleSubmit(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, httpMethod: 'PUT', updateTargetId: 'result' });"
        }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value='1'/>
    <input type="submit" value="OK Put" />
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index2","Home", 
    new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "result", 
            HttpMethod = "DELETE"
        }, 
    new
        {
            onclick = "Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event));",
            onsubmit="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleSubmit(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, httpMethod: 'DELETE', updateTargetId: 'result' });"
        }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value='1'/>
    <input type="submit" value="Error Delete" />
}
```

In the first one, I'm excecuting a `PUT` and the second one a `DELETE`, but In fiddler alway says that are `POST`.

To continue testing, I added a code (this code is only with test proposals)

```
(function () {
    var origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (a) {
        console.log("~>" + a);
    //console.log(this);
    var x = a;
    this.addEventListener('load', function () {
        //console.log(this);
        if(x == "POST"){
                 alert("Was a POST");
            }
        });
        origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})();
```

Why my other HttpVerbs always are excecuted as a `POST`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman basically, it's different, because the problem it's based on the thread solution and releated with the `MVC` notation and the problem not it's with `jquery`, it's with `Razor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears from the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.httpmethod%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) that GET and POST are only two verbs supported by `HttpMethod` property:

> Gets or sets the HTTP request method ("Get" or "Post").

So what probably happens is that PUT or DELETE you are using are not accepted, and property defaults to POST:

> The HTTP request method. The default value is "Post".

Comment: You beat me to it! :<

Comment: I found this value: `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (a, b) { console.log(b);  }); `  And that's returns: `~>Method: POST - http://localhost:5773/Home/Index2?Length=4&id=1&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&X-HTTP-Method-Override=DELETE` and the `HTTP-Method-Override` has the `PUT` and `DELETE` override method

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to "override" HTTP Method at `OnBegin` of Ajax.BeginForm:

First set JavaScript function to be called at `OnBegin`

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("", "", null, new AjaxOptions()
    {                   
        OnBegin = "beginSubmit",
        ...
```

And then - in the JavaScript function - change the request type to `PUT`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function beginSubmit(xhr, o) {
        o.type = "PUT";
    }
</script>
```